# Inherit and modify the account.report_invoice_document table

Tags: xml, templates, report, odoo, odoo-12

Hi I'm trying to create a pdf inheriting the report template account.report_invoice_document for replacing table. But I have this problem

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'with_context' 
Error to render compiling AST AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'with_context' 
Template: 1045 Path: /templates/t/t/t[1] 
Node: <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=lang)"/>
```

Without inheriting it, I have no problem

my code:

```xml
<template id="certificate_donation_template" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
    <xpath expr="//table[@name='invoice_line_table']" position="replace">
        <table class="table table-condensed" name="invoice_line_table">
            <thead>
                <th class="text-center" style="width: 70%">Code</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Date done</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Amount</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Payment Method</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <t t-as="doc" t-foreach="docs">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="doc['donation_name']"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <span t-esc="doc['donation_date_done']"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <span t-esc="doc['donation_amount']"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <span t-esc="doc['payment_method']"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </t>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

report

```
    <report 
        attachment_use="True" 
        id="certificate_report" 
        menu="False"
        name="ngo_payment_certificate.certificate_donation_template" 
        paperformat="ngo_payment_certification_donation_certificate" 
        report_type="qweb-pdf" 
        string="Donations Certificate"
        model="ngo.donor"
        ></report>
```

On **__manifest__** I have in depends account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only inherit qweb template if both are belongs to same model.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here with doc and you should use **`o`** to call fields in print out

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="o.donation_name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <span t-esc="o.donation_date_done"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <span t-esc="o.donation_amount"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <span t-esc="o.payment_method"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </t>
```

If donation_name is in account.invoice model.

Comment: No the fields are not on the account model, but on mine. I'm just trying to use the account template and replace the table.